# Apply a conditional style to a crosstab with parameter

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I am currently trying to apply a style that basicaly changes to colour of the measures(detail) text field in a crosstab to indicate the date that was chosen via a parameter that the user must imput at the start of the report. Here are the steps I followed:

1. I created a parameter $P{Date} as java.sql.timestamp and checked "is for prompting"
2. Created the same parameter $P{Date} in my Dataset query with same info as previous parameter (this dataset is gonna be used to fill the crosstab)
3. Create the same parameter $P{Date} in my crosstab item, also same info as before
4. On my crosstab properties in "Dataset" I added my parameter with same name "Date" and expression $P{Date} and left parameters Map as blank

So far the report runs fine and the data parameter is working for my crosstab, filtering the data by the date chosen for the parameter.

5. Created my conditional style (Style1) with the following expression:

   ```
   AND(MONTH(${crosstab_month}).equals(MONTH($P{Date})),
        YEAR(${crosstab_month}).equals(YEAR($P{Date})),
         DAY(${crosstab_month}).equals(01))
   ```

${crosstab_month} is the column group that displays the Date (contains the first day of each month, and is also a timestamp).

Now when I run the report I can't seem to get this to work, I put the markup on all fields as "styled" and in the "Style and Print Details" as Style1.

Am I forgetting something? I don't understand why this is not working, because if I change the $P{Date} with NOW() in the style expression it works... is the $P{Date} value somehow not evaluating correctly as a date/timestamp?

Comment: What you might be missing is passing $P{Date} to the subdataset.  That would be done inside the dataset run (part of the crosstab dataset definition).

Comment: Isn't that the step 3 and 4?

Comment: Right, my bad.  Can you show $P{Date} in a crosstab text field (e.g. the one that uses Style1), to verify the value for the crosstab parameter?

Comment: I added the $P{Date} to my crosstab but it shows as "null". What am i missing here?

Comment: Post your JRXML (preferably a minimal version that illustrates the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i made a workaround to fix this issue, and that was the alter the query to get a value of the input parameter $P{Date}, and insert a new column in my crosstab (with w=0 and h=0).

After that i altered the style condition to;

```
AND(MONTH(${crosstab_month}).equals(MONTH($V{ReportDate})),
 YEAR(${crosstab_month}).equals(YEAR($V{ReportDate})),
  DAY(${crosstab_month}).equals(01))
```

$V{ReportDate} is the name of the new column group on the crosstab.

Hope this helps! :)
Thank you!